# Find and replace 'French quotes' («») in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having trouble doing a find and replace in Word 2007.

I have a document with a load of French quotes which should be followed by non-breakable spaces, but are currently followed by normal spaces.

Rather than going through by hand, I want to do a find and replace of `"« "` with `«nbsp;` (or whatever the Word equivalent is).

The Find works fine, but the `«` gets replaced as `"`.

Any ideas? Everything that Google throws up is about SmartQuotes, which isn't my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have to uncheck the autocorrect quotes box in the Autocorrect tab (using MS Office 2010 in italian: it should be under Options > Correction Options > Autocorrect Options; in previous versions I don't know, in 2003 and before it should be under the Options menu). After unchecking:

In the document copy once the `«` symbol.
In the Replace tab paste the `«` symbol in both find and replace spaces and in the find space add a `space` while in the replace line add a non-breakable space (by holding down `shift` and `ctrl` while pressing `space`).
Replace All

Comment: Thanks! I was worried I was going to have to write myself a macro.

Comment: I'd upvote this again if I could!